# Select all transparent objects

Tags: python

I have imported a large IFC-file using BlendeBIM and want to select all objects with some transparency (viewport display color alpha > 0) and wonder how to do this with a python script? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The viewport color can be accessed with [bpy.types.Object.color](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.color) and the alpha is the fourth element of the color iterator : $(Red, Green, Blue, Alpha)$.

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selectable_objects:
    obj.select_set(obj.color[3] < 1)
    
# Not mandatory : Change active object
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In this case most of the window objects consists of solid and transparent parts. I need to separate the glazed/transparent part for each object into a new object with only transparent content and wonder how to do this, so far I have separated each trasparent object into a separate object and that is not very practical for windows with multiple panes.

Comment: @user2404987 You can easily separate objects by material with P (in edit mode) > By Material. It works with multiple objects selected at the same time